# java.io.File(parent, child) does not work as expected

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to construct a Java File object based on a user provided file name (could be absolute or relative) and a environment dependent base directory. The java doc for java.io.File(File parent, String child) says the following:

> If the child pathname string is absolute then it **is converted into a relative pathname** in a system-dependent way.

That made me think that if I have the following code:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(new File("C:/Temp"),"C:/Temp/file.txt");
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

the output would be

```
C:\Temp\file.txt
```

and then I'd be in business because it would not really matter anymore if the user provided an absolute or relative path. But in fact, the output is

```
C:\Temp\C:\Temp\file.txt
```

Which means I have to figure out the exact relative path (or at least test different options to see if the file exists). Am I misunderstanding the JavaDoc?

Comment: The child pathname has to be a relative pathname. The conversion talks about slashes vs. backslashes, I think. In your case, you'd have to figure out if the path is absolute before you proceed.

Comment: Is the behaviour the same if you use the (more correct) `"C:\\Temp"` and `"C:\\Temp\\file.txt"` instead of using forward-clashes? I don't have a Windows PC with a JDK installed here at the moment, so I can't test this. Also: what does `new File("C:/Temp").isAbsolute()` print?

Comment: @Joachim: Both `"C:/Temp"` and `"C:\\Temp"` are treated the same. `new File("C:/Temp").isAbsolute()` prints `true`.

Comment: @Joachim - `isAbsolute` returns true for all the four paths - no matter which slash is used

Comment: I found out in testing that if you do `new File("directory", "/file")` and `new File("directory", "file"), they will both result in the absolute path "directory/file". The first one will not result in "directory//file".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ***If the child pathname string is absolute then it is converted into a relative pathname in a system-dependent way.***

I assume this means that even if you provide an absolute path, it will be converted to (in a system dependent way), and treated as, a relative path.

> ***Which means I have to figure out the exact relative path (or at least test different options to see if the file exists).***

Yes, I believe so.

This could perhaps be easily done with

```
file.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(parent.getAbsolutePath());
```

to check if it is an absolute path to a directory in `parent`, and

```
file.getAbsolutePath().substring(parent.getAbsolutePath().length());
```

to get the relative part.

Comment: Hmm, you could be right when saying the absolute path is treated as a relative path (it's certainly what it looks like). That would be  a shame (and poor JavaDoc imho ;-)). I'll mess about with your suggestions a bit to see what works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With your base directory expressed as a `Path`, e.g.

```
Path basePath = new File("C:/Temp").toPath();
```

you can use `Path.resolve` to determine the `Path` (or `File`) for your `fileName`, regardless of whether it is absolute or relative:

```
Path path = basePath.resolve(fileName).normalize();
File file = path.toFile();
```

The additional `normalize` here simply takes care of cleaning up any `.` or `..` from the path.